# How do I check if a file exists inside a certain directory in Batch?

Tags: batch-file, directory

How would I go about making a program that scans for a certain file inside a certain directory, not on the C:\ drive?

I know that IF EXIST does find a certain file, but I want it to to only try to find a certain file inside a certain directory, not on the C:\ as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the full path and filename to the `IF EXIST` and it will only check in that specified folder.

```
IF EXIST "C:\folder\folder2\file.ext" ...
```

---

Edited by Magoo - added quotes which are required if the full path contains spaces or some other characters

Comment: So, for example, I was looking for hi.txt in C:Windows, I would go IF EXIST "C:Windows" hi.txt, or IF EXIST hi.txt "C:Windows"?

Comment: The whole path and file name need to be in quotes if there are any spaces: `IF EXIST "C:Windows\hi.txt"`